# My code won't work in Chrome but works fine in JSFiddle

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I am having a problem. I found a code of a carousel online which I tought was good. I tried to copy it into new html, css and js files, for so to open the file, but the carousel won't work in Chrome even though it works fine in JSFiddle and Codepin.

It says that the code ( $(document).keydown(function(e) { is ) is uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined.

Thank you for your help in advance!

```js
function moveToSelected(element) {

  if (element == "next") {
    var selected = $(".selected").next();
  } else if (element == "prev") {
    var selected = $(".selected").prev();
  } else {
    var selected = element;
  }

  var next = $(selected).next();
  var prev = $(selected).prev();
  var prevSecond = $(prev).prev();
  var nextSecond = $(next).next();

  $(selected).removeClass().addClass("selected");

  $(prev).removeClass().addClass("prev");
  $(next).removeClass().addClass("next");

  $(nextSecond).removeClass().addClass("nextRightSecond");
  $(prevSecond).removeClass().addClass("prevLeftSecond");

  $(nextSecond).nextAll().removeClass().addClass('hideRight');
  $(prevSecond).prevAll().removeClass().addClass('hideLeft');

}

// Eventos teclado
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    switch(e.which) {
        case 37: // left
        moveToSelected('prev');
        break;

        case 39: // right
        moveToSelected('next');
        break;

        default: return;
    }
    e.preventDefault();
});

$('#carousel div').click(function() {
  moveToSelected($(this));
});

$('#prev').click(function() {
  moveToSelected('prev');
});

$('#next').click(function() {
  moveToSelected('next');
});
```

```css
html, body, main {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#carousel {
  position: relative;
  height: 400px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  overflow: hidden;
}
#carousel div {
  position: absolute;
  transition: transform 1s, left 1s, opacity 1s, z-index 0s;
  opacity: 1;
}
#carousel div img {
  width: 400px;
  transition: width 1s;
}
#carousel div.hideLeft {
  left: 0%;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(50%) translateX(-50%);
}
#carousel div.hideLeft img {
  width: 200px;
}
#carousel div.hideRight {
  left: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(50%) translateX(-50%);
}
#carousel div.hideRight img {
  width: 200px;
}
#carousel div.prev {
  z-index: 5;
  left: 30%;
  transform: translateY(50px) translateX(-50%);
}
#carousel div.prev img {
  width: 300px;
}
#carousel div.prevLeftSecond {
  z-index: 4;
  left: 15%;
  transform: translateY(50%) translateX(-50%);
  opacity: 0.7;
}
#carousel div.prevLeftSecond img {
  width: 200px;
}
#carousel div.selected {
  z-index: 10;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateY(0px) translateX(-50%);
}
#carousel div.next {
  z-index: 5;
  left: 70%;
  transform: translateY(50px) translateX(-50%);
}
#carousel div.next img {
  width: 300px;
}
#carousel div.nextRightSecond {
  z-index: 4;
  left: 85%;
  transform: translateY(50%) translateX(-50%);
  opacity: 0.7;
}
#carousel div.nextRightSecond img {
  width: 200px;
}

.buttons {
  position: fixed;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<main>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Carousel.css">
<script src="Carousel.js"></script>

    <div id="carousel">

       <div class="hideLeft">
        <img src="https://s16.postimg.org/vklrwoxtx/cover9.jpg">
      </div>

      <div class="prevLeftSecond">
        <img src="https://s16.postimg.org/cgsggckzp/cover8.jpg">
      </div>

      <div class="prev">
        <img src="https://s16.postimg.org/emmrauog5/cover7.jpg">
      </div>

      <div class="selected">
        <img src="https://s16.postimg.org/9drqcz611/cover1.jpg">
      </div>

      <div class="next">
        <img src="https://s16.postimg.org/pnhwfvgp1/cover6.jpg">
      </div>

      <div class="nextRightSecond">
        <img src="
https://s16.postimg.org/edp6kxbnp/cover4.jpg">
      </div>

      <div class="hideRight">
        <img src="https://s16.postimg.org/fij8qay4l/cover3.jpg">
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="buttons">
      <button id="prev">Prev</button>
      <button id="next">Next</button>
    </div>

  </main>
```

Comment: Your snippet is running just fine. How are you testing this in your local?

Comment: Did you check the browser console for error messages? Also, running HTML in the `file:///` environment can cause trouble.

Comment: No, it says: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined at Carousel.js:30, then it comes a red line under this code: $(document).keydown(function(e) {,

Comment: Well there you go.... that is a very common error message so I'm sure a quick Google will show you whats wrong :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should wait for [document ready](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) event before running your JS.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 //your code here
});
```